# Retrieve multiple objects using JPA

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, jdbc

I recently switched over to JPA (EclipseLink) after a few months using plain JDBC and I'm rebuilding one of my applications using the API.

A quick background: I have two tables in a MySQL database. The table that the CandidateBean represents uses its primary key as a foreign key in the "Ref" column in the SearchCriteria table.

I want to retrieve the objects in such a way that if I retrieve the CandidateBean, it automatically retrieves the SearchCriteria object that it is linked to. I understand retrieval for single entities and JPQL queries but I'm pretty sure there's a straightforward way to do it in JPA that doesn't involve multiple queries/joins like in JDBC.

I have the following code:

CandidateBean:

```
// Tells JPA that this class defines an entity to be stored in a database
@Entity
// Overrides default table name
@Table(name = "CandidateUsers")
// Maps CandidateProfile table to this entity
public class CandidateBean implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

// Overriding column names to match database tables
@Column(name = "FName")
private String fName;
@Column(name = "LName")
private String lName;
@Column(name = "Pass")
private String password;
@Column(name = "Email")
private String email;
// Tells JPA that the following field is the primary key for this entity
@Id
// Tells JPA to use auto-incremented values of the MySQL table as the userID
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "UserID")
private int userID = 0;
etc etc constructors/getters/setters
```

SearchCriteria:

```
//Tells JPA that this class defines an entity to be stored in a database
@Entity
//Overrides default table name
@Table(name = "SearchCriteria")
public class SearchCriteria implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

// Tells JPA that the following field is the primary key for this entity
@Id
// Tells JPA to use auto-incremented values of the MySQL table as the userID
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
// Overriding column names to match database tables
@Column(name = "SearchID")
private int searchID;
@Column(name = "State")
private String state;
@Column(name = "Field")
private String field;
@Column(name = "Cert")
private String certification;
@Column(name = "CompDate")
private String date;
@Column(name = "School")
private String school;

@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name="Ref", referencedColumnName = "UserID")
private CandidateBean user;
etc etc constructors/getters/setters
```

Please let me know if I need to clarify something. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by Dhruv Rai Puri, JPA allows you to map the collection of SearchCriteria's associated to a CandidateBean using a OneToMany mapping, described here:
https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Mapping/Relationship_Mappings/Collection_Mappings/OneToMany

For your model, it is simply:

```
  @ManyToOne(mappedBy = "user")
  List<SearchCriteria> searchCriterias;
```

Note that the mappedBy refers to the mapping on the user property in SearchCriteria, and so will use the join column specified there.  It makes the relationship bidirectional, and controlled by the 'user'; changes to the 'user' in SearchCriteria will change the field in the database regardless of changes to the collection in CandidateBean, but both should be kept in synch for caching purposes.  The above mapping defaults to lazy fetching, which means it will trigger a query for the associated instances when accessed if they aren't already cached in the object.

From there, you can control how and when this collection is retrieved through various JPA and native EclipseLink settings - you can set that the relationship is always fetched a certain way, or decide to change it on a query by query basis.  See 
http://vard-lokkur.blogspot.com/2011/05/eclipselink-jpa-queries-optimization.html

Comment: That clarified everything, I really appreciate the detailed response. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Just like you have put a @ManyToOne in SearchCriteria, put a reverese @OneToMany in CandidateBean which will a List/Set of SearchCriterias. Now when you fetch a record of CandidateBean, you will get the linked SearchCriterias automatically. You can fetch the linked records in LAZY or EAGER way as per your needs.

Also there is no need for a separate JOIN etc., @OneToMany mapping is enough